# *ngFor in a button is not working in Angular

Tags: html, angular, for-loop, button, ngfor

I have a datatable with a button at each row. This button works

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="action(car.id)">Action</button>
```

I'm trying to create a button that call action(car.id) for all the rows of the datatable, so for all the car.id

```
<button>
    <div *ngFor='let cars of car'>
      <span (click)='this.action(cars.id)'>Action</span>
    </div>
</button>
```

The button returns just ONE od the ids
I tried to modify it by changing the location of the *ngFor but it stills not working.
If I put the *ngFor in the button tag, it creates multiple buttons that works, but I just need one button to click on it

Comment: Are you sure it's `let cars of car` instead of `let car of cars`? Also, there shouldn't be a `this` in the function, it's implied.

Comment: I tried let car or cars, but in my case it's cars of car. It's a mistake but it works. Also I tried to add this. but it changed nothing. It stills return just one id

Comment: It works for me. [Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ymm7e?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I need a unique button that return car 1, car 2, car 3 ... I also have the same result as you, multiple buttons that work separatly

Comment: I'm now trying with a trackBy

Comment: Can I ask why a unique button? What if you have one button per car? Does that works for your needs?

Anyways, I just tried @DanielB 's code (and also tweak it to looks more like yours) and worked as you requested.

Comment: Feel free to shae some more code to see if we're missing something. Maybe your cars array? Or even your table layout so we may understand why you need only one button (maybe there's a *better* approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inside your component ts file**

```
public actionForAll(){
  this.cars.forEach((car) => {
     this.action(car.id)
   });
}
```

**Inside your component html file**

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="actionForAll()">Action</button>
```

Comment: please mark answer as accepted if it has solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

your ts should be like this for use binding in * ngFor

```
 action(x:any){

  console.log(x)
  return this.cars
 }
```

then you can:

```
<div *ngFor="let car of cars">
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="action(car.id)">Action</button>
</div>
```